# Simple binding is not working in wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm new to WPF MVVM, I'm trying to get a simple binding to work, but I'm unable to.

- The Binding works fine when I set the property in the ViewModel constructor
- The Binding doesn't update UI when I set the property through a function

Here is my ViewModel

```
private UserIdentifier ? selectedUser;
public UserIdentifier ? SelectedUser {
  get {
    return selectedUser;
  }
  set {
    selectedUser = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedUser));
    if (selectedUser != null && selectedUser.Id != null) {
      Debug.print("The User Has Been Selected from the listview"); // I Can see this 
      GetSiteDetails();
    }
  }
}

private UserDetails ? _userDetails;
public UserDetails ? UserDetails {
  get {
    return _userDetails;
  }
  set {
    _userDetails = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(UserDetails));
    if (UserDetails is not null)
      Debug.Print("Address: " + UserDetails.Address);
  }
}

private void GetSiteDetails() {
  Debug.print("I'm here"); // I Can see this 
  UserDetails = new UserDetails {
    Address = "Address Test 1",
      Style = "Style 1"
  }; //Binding doesn't work here
}

public ViewModel() {
  UserDetails = new UserDetails {
    Address = "Address Test 0",
      Style = "Style 0"
  };   //Binding works here and I can see UI populated
}
```

Comment: We still don't know if you are setting SelectedUser on a different view model instance than the one to which the view is bound. Show us the code where you set the property.

Comment: @Clemens
SelectedUser is binded to listview in XAML, SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser, Mode=TwoWay}"

Comment: And the view that shows the UserDetails uses the same view model?

Comment: Yes, the view uses the same viewmodel, it does populate Userdetails when it's set in Viewmodel constructor within the same viewmodel class, the only issue here is that the view doesn't update when I set UserDetails anywhere outside Viewmodel constructor.
SelectedUser is set automatically when I choose an item from the Listview, the event SelectedItem of the listview triggers the binding with Selected User

Comment: @Clemens thank you, I fixed the issue, I was instancing the viewmodel in every view. Now I declare viewmodel at the app level, and use it in all views, it solved the issue, but not sure if that's a good practice

Comment: That's totally good practice.